# VSCode integrated terminal pass CTRL+SPACE to Clink

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I am using Clink for Windows and it works mostly fine in the integrated terminal from VSCode. Since it is invoked via `ctrl+space` I tried removing all related VSCode keybindings. With `shift+alt+?` (clinks keybinding browser) I found that VSCode sends the wrong keystrokes when pressing `ctrl+space`:

```
C-@ : set-mark -- Set the mark to the cursor point.  If a numeric argument is supplied, sets the mark to that position
```

When I am in a normal terminal I get:

```
C-Space : clink-select-complete -- Perform completion by selecting from an interactive list of possible completions; if there is only one match, insert it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [asking](https://github.com/chrisant996/clink/discussions/423) around, it turns out this is an [issue with xterm](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/2357). VSCode remaps some keybindings to make them work in PowerShell, that's why I get CTRL+SHIFT+2 which is interpreted as CTRL+@.
So for now a workaround is necessary:
Put `"\C-@": clink-select-complete` into your `.inputrc`